# Gyroscope shaking when moving around

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I'm making a 360 video player with the camera placed in the center of a sphere and I've implemented the gyroscope into the camera, it is working but when I move around there is weird shake going on, looks like having some sort of delay even when the phone is still.
The screen orientation is locked in landscape.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gyro : MonoBehaviour {

    private Gyroscope gyro;
    private bool gyroSupported;
    private Quaternion rotFix;


    void Start()
    {
        gyroSupported = SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope;

        GameObject camParent = new GameObject("camParent");
        camParent.transform.position = transform.position;
        transform.parent = camParent.transform;

        if (gyroSupported)
        {
            gyro = Input.gyro;
            gyro.enabled = true;

            camParent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 180f, 0f);
            rotFix = new Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0);
        }
    }



    void Update()
    {
        this.transform.Rotate(-Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x, -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y, -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.z);
    }




}
```

Comment: What is the brand of your phone and the model number? Have you tested other phones as well?

Comment: @Hristo I´ve tested on an Iphone 5c and a Samsung s5, both with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The following code should fix the issue:

```
void Update() 
{
    this.transform.Rotate (-Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x, -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y, -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.z);
}
```

Referenced from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/970891/rotating-a-camera-using-the-gyroscope.html).

Comment: it works! but there is an issue, the camera is not center anymore.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't stay in the same position or?

Comment: looks like the video is pending to the right, I have to rotate the phone like 30 degrees and then look around

Comment: The issue might be coming from somewhere else or I am mistaken?

Comment: I don't know, it wasn't happening before

Comment: My answer has been edited please take a look and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144364/discussion-between-and4011002849-and-hristo).

Comment: it isn't working, there is a strange rotation on the z axis

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But in my case it turned out that it's the problem in most of mobile phones. May be gyro scope is not mature enough yet. Although It's not a coding problem. And you are not the only one facing this problem. I also tried many blogs that time. But there was no proper coding solution. This is a bug in circuit. **NO CURE YET**

Answer (score 0):

Using Gyro plugin in Krpano Library. Updating the Library from krpano 1.19-pr14 to krpano 1.19-pr16 fixed this issue for me